# Folder research task

Tags: shell-script, find, logs, directory

I have a folder with 3 subfolders containing 6 files each.There are 2 files in each subfolders with `:NOPM` in their file names.

I need to create a shell script that checks all the folders and their subfolders. If there are any file names with `:NOPM`, then this should be removed from the name. If there is another file with the same name, it should be deleted and every interaction should be logged into a log.txt.

Comment: welcome to U&L, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: find /mydirectoryname  -name *:nopm:*
I just can find the files, but i'm start learning unix now, and can't solve this.

Comment: What part of this is giving you problems? Are you just expecting us to do your homework for you?

Comment: You need to get all files, then check their names in cycle and move(rename) or delete files, depending of names. So, welcome to the Linux way! :)

Comment: I should complete the task like this. Can you help to 
repair this?

for 
if find /data/irm/Example_September -name *:nopm:* mv file --?
do echo I rename the file.   --?
elif echo I remove the file. 
fi
>> /data/irm/Example_September/log.txt \;

Answer (score 0):

```
find /mydirectory -maxdepth 3 -iname *:nomp* -execdir bash -c 'for f; do base=${f##*/}; mv -- "$f" "${f%/*}/${base//:nomp/whateverYouWant}" && echo $f >> /PATH/log.txt; done' _ {} +
```

By the way, because I used execdir you might not need to use base=${f##*/} and instead of ${base//:nomp.....} you can replace "base" with "."

Comment: Thanks for help, but i should complete the task like this, but it doensn't works.